# Why does switch-case in my javascript function not work?

Tags: javascript

When I run my HTML-page and click on the select-boxes the switch-case statement in my script always returns the default value instead of one of the specific cases. I can't find out why this happens. Here is my code:

```js
function getvalue(offer) {

  var code = document.getElementById('channel1');
  var dtc = document.getElementById('channel2');
    var channelX = document.getElementById('channel3');
    var remark = document.getElementById('subchannel');

  switch (offer) {
  case "CC-C":
   code.value = "user1";
   dtc.value = "Position1"+remark;
      channelX.value = "VBnet";
   break;
  case "CC-D":
   code.value = "user2";
   dtc.value = "Postion2";
      channelX.value = "VBnet";
   break;
  default:
   code.value = "Owner";
   dtc.value = "Admin";
      channelX.value = "VBnet";
  }
 }
```

```html
<select class="validate[required] text-input form-control form-text required" id="channel1" name="submitted[channel1]" onchange="getvalue(this.value)">
          <option value="">Choosechoice
          </option>
          <option value="CC-C">Height
          </option>
          <option value="CC-D">Low
          </option>
</select>          
<select class="validate[required] text-input form-control form-text required" id="subchannel" name="submitted-subchannel" onfocusout="getvalue(this.value)">
<option value="">Choosechoice</option>
 <option value="Walkin">Medium</option>
 <option value="Walkout">Small</option>
 </select>

<input class="form-control form-text" id="channel3" maxlength="128" name="channel3" size="60" style="display:none;" type="text" value="info" />
    <input class="form-control form-text" id="channel2" maxlength="128" name="description" size="60" style="display:none" type="text" value="Choosechoiceplease" />
```

Comment: Where is the HTML-code that contains elements with the ids `channel2` and `channel3`? I can't see any. The only ids I can see in your snippets are `channel1` and `subchannel`. You cannot obtain any value if there are no matching ids in your HTML-code.

Comment: last update help me please

Comment: What on Earth are you asking?

Comment: i want to know. how to string + string in case under code

Comment: @TanaphonPrayoonprasop you have to first debug and check the value of ```offer```.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is your solution. You can't say

```
onchange="getvalue(this.value)"
```

or

```
onfocusout="getvalue(this.value)"
```

The resulting `offer` is always `undefined` as HTML can't handle the object structure that way.

You have to simply pass it this way

```
onchange="getvalue(this)"
onfocusout="getvalue(this)"
```

---

```
    <select class="validate[required] text-input form-control form-text required" id="channel1" name="submitted[channel1]" onchange="getvalue(this)">
        <option value="">
            Choosechoice
        </option>
        <option value="CC-C">
            Height
        </option>
        <option value="CC-D">
            Low
        </option>
    </select>
    <select class="validate[required] text-input form-control form-text required" id="subchannel" name="submitted-subchannel" onfocusout="getvalue(this)">
        <option value="">
            Choosechoice
        </option>
        <option value="Walkin">
            Medium
        </option>
        <option value="Walkout">
            Small
        </option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-control form-text" id="channel3" maxlength="128" name="channel3" size="60" style="display:none;" type="text" value="info" /> 
    <input class="form-control form-text" id="channel2" maxlength="128" name="description" size="60" style="display:none" type="text" value="Choosechoiceplease" />
```

and then in your script handle it like this

```
function getvalue(offer) {

    var code = document.getElementById('channel1');
    var dtc = document.getElementById('channel2');
    var channelX = document.getElementById('channel3');
    var remark = document.getElementById('subchannel');

    console.log('code: ', code.value);
    console.log('dtc: ', dtc.value);
    console.log('channelX: ', channelX.value);
    console.log('remark: ', remark.value);
    console.log('offer: ', offer.value);


    switch (offer.value.trim()) {
        case "CC-C":
            code.value = "user1";
            dtc.value = "Position1"+remark;
            channelX.value = "VBnet";
            console.log('matching CC-C');
            break;
        case "CC-D":
            code.value = "user2";
            dtc.value = "Postion2";
            channelX.value = "VBnet";
            console.log('matching CC-D');
            break;
        default:
            code.value = "Owner";
            dtc.value = "Admin";
            channelX.value = "VBnet";
            console.log('defaulting');
    }
}
```

Comment: Functional value result default only not work in case

Comment: Sorry mate, haven't seen that `offer.value` returns an additional blank. Don't know where it derives from. Adding the `trim()` function in the switch-header solved this issue. Please check again.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem. Thanks in advance!